# Rotation and multiple windows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, rotation, uiwindow

I'm creating a video player that manages full screen mode trying to emulate the `MPMoviePlayerController` behavior. In fact when you press the full screen button, the player view is moved to another `UIWindow` instance.
Right after the button is pressed the code generates a window with a `rootViewController` that host the player view.
The app can manage only the portrait orientation, but the view controller that hosts the player on the new window only landscape.
Everything works fine: if I press full screen the simulator rotates to landscape displaying the player in full screen.
The problem arise when I want the app to return in normal visualization, the window disappear and it returns to the "app" the problem is that the status bar remains in landscape.
On iOS8 nothing works but that is another story.
The app view controllers are set to support only portrait:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger orietationMask = 0;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        orietationMask = (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight);
    }
    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        orietationMask = (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
    }
    return orietationMask;
}
```

Only the view controller that will host the player view in another window is set to support only landscape.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSUInteger orietationMask = 0;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        orietationMask = (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
    }
    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
        orietationMask = (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape )  ;

    }
    return orietationMask;
}
```

Here a short brief about methods I use to create the window and swap views:

```
- (void) createWindow {
    self.playerWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;
    self.playerWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal;
    self.fullScreenViewController = [[FullScreenPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    self.playerWindow.rootViewController = self.fullScreenViewController;
}

- (void) swapPlayerViewHost {
    self.oldHostingView = self.playerView.superview;
    UIView * playerView = self.playerView;
    [playerView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.fullScreenViewController.view addSubview:playerView];
    playerView.frame = self.fullScreenViewController.bounds;

}
- (void) restorePlayerViewPosition {
    UIView * playerView = self.playerView;
    [playerView removeFromSuperview];
    [self.oldHostingView addSubview:playerView];
    playerView.frame = self.oldHostingView.bounds;
    [self.oldWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.playerWindow.hidden = YES;
    self.oldHostingView = nil;
    self.playerWindow = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Movie controller methods


- (void) setFullScreen:(BOOL) fullScreen {
    if (fullScreen) {
        // Create window
        [self createWindow];
        // Swap player view
        [self swapPlayerViewHost];
        // Make view visible
        [self.playerWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        _fullScreen = YES;
    }
    else {
        [self restorePlayerViewPosition];
        _fullScreen = NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Having the same problem now...

Comment: I don't remember well, but maybe I created my own player in its own view view controller, by using preferredInterfaceOrientation, shouldRotate etc

Comment: That solution don't work on iOS8 if i use modalPresentaionStyleCustom. So i tried adding a new window. It kind of works except the status bar orientation thing. Thanks anyway.